Ubuntu 24.04LTS Consuming extreme battery power
I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS. Everything is good except for a few bugs. The major thing I noticed is that its consuming power so rapidly like 100-0 in just 1 hour. With 22.04 my new acer nitro 5 laptop use to run min 2-3 hours, but now I have to charge it every hour. Anyone know the reason or solution to this?
Acer nitro-5 gaming laptop
16, 500SSD,
Intel , nvidia 1650 GTX

the same issue is happening with me

I haven't had any issues on ubuntu 24, but as someone with a NVIDIA GPU, I didn't realise how badly it drains battery. If you go into NVIDIA Settings and then PRIME profiles, set it to Intel (Power Saving Mode). My battery life went from 1-2 hours to 6-7 hours, and I had this issue for nearly a year. Felt like an idiot when I finally decided to look into it. I hope this helps!
Edit: you can also set NVIDIA to only run on certain apps e.g. games if you want, but if you're just using ubuntu for non-gpu activities then I'd just switch it off

I'm using Ryzen 5600H can we have any solution for that. Kidnly.....
